# Tibble/Data_frame is not rounding using mutate_if()

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding, tibble

I've got a `tibble` with similar characteristics to this:

```
set.seed(123)


df <- tibble(
  x = sample(LETTERS[1:3],10,T),
  y = rdunif(10,7.5),
  z = rdunif(10,7.5)
)
```

Which yields:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   x         y     z
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A      8.00  7.00
 2 C      4.00  6.00
 3 B      6.00  5.00
 4 C      5.00  8.00
 5 C      1.00  5.00
 6 A      7.00  6.00
 7 B      2.00  5.00
 8 C      1.00  5.00
 9 B      3.00  3.00
10 B      8.00  2.00
```

I'd like to round the numeric variables using `mutate_if()`; I'm using this code.

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(round(., 1)))
```

Which yields the same as above (no rounding).

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   x         y     z
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A      8.00  7.00
 2 C      4.00  6.00
 3 B      6.00  5.00
 4 C      5.00  8.00
 5 C      1.00  5.00
 6 A      7.00  6.00
 7 B      2.00  5.00
 8 C      1.00  5.00
 9 B      3.00  3.00
10 B      8.00  2.00
```

I'm not getting any warnings, and the code seems to run fine. I just don't get the answer I'm expecting.

ANSWER

I wasn't asking the right question. I'm looking to limit the number of digits of numeric columns in a `tibble`. I was looking for the `sprintf` function in baseR.

```
df %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(sprintf("%0.1f", .)))
```

Comment: Works fine using `runif(10)` in your code instead of `rdunif(.)`.

Comment: Thanks, see my edit to the question. I was looking to limit the number of decimals using a pipe approach.

Comment: Here there are even no digits shown. `# A tibble: 10 x 3
   x         y     z
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A         8     7
 2 C         4     6
 3 B         6     5`

Answer (score 1):

Set the number of significant digits when tibbles print

```
options(pillar.sigfig=1)
```

The different [options](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.4.2/topics/tibble-options) to control tibble printing

I generated new data which I show below before & after setting options

```
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
   # x          y      z
   # <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 # 1 A     0.0458 0.665 
 # 2 B     0.442  0.0948
 # 3 B     0.799  0.384 
 # 4 B     0.122  0.274 
 # 5 A     0.561  0.815 
 # 6 A     0.207  0.449 
 # 7 A     0.128  0.810 
 # 8 B     0.753  0.812 
 # 9 A     0.895  0.794 
# 10 C     0.374  0.440 


# # A tibble: 10 x 3
   # x         y     z
   # <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 # 1 A      0.05  0.7 
 # 2 B      0.4   0.09
 # 3 B      0.8   0.4 
 # 4 B      0.1   0.3 
 # 5 A      0.6   0.8 
 # 6 A      0.2   0.4 
 # 7 A      0.1   0.8 
 # 8 B      0.8   0.8 
 # 9 A      0.9   0.8 
# 10 C      0.4   0.4
```